# Unable to mount EFS to ECS on fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

trying to mount EFS to ECS Fargate but getting below error while task is being executed. it looks as though it is an IAM issue but crosschecked all the roles and unable to identify the issue. Checked security groups as well.i allowed 2049 port and attached ecs security group to it.

> "ResourceInitializationError: failed to invoke EFS utils commands to set up EFS volumes: stderr: b'mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting 127.0.0.1:/' : unsuccessful EFS utils command execution; code: 32"

**Terraform 0.12 and Fargate 1.4.0**

```
resource "aws_efs_file_system" efs {
  creation_token   = "${var.prefix}-${var.appName}-ecs"
  encrypted        = true
  kms_key_id       = data.aws_kms_key.efs_kms_key.arn
  performance_mode = var.performance_mode
  throughput_mode  = var.throughput_mode
  tags            = var.tags
}


resource "aws_efs_mount_target" efs_mount {

  count           = length(module.vpc_presets.subnet_ids)
  file_system_id  = aws_efs_file_system.efs.id
  subnet_id       = flatten(module.vpc_presets.subnet_ids)[count.index]
  security_groups = data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state_sg.outputs.efs_sg

}
resource "aws_efs_access_point" this  {
  file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.efs.id
}
```

```
data "template_file" jenkins_container_def {
  template = file("${path.module}/templates/jenkins.json.tpl")

  vars = {
    name                = "${var.prefix}-${var.appName}-${var.env}"
    jenkins_controller_port = var.jenkins_port
    jnlp_port           = var.jnlp_port
    source_volume       = "${var.appName}-efs"
    jenkins_home        = "/var/jenkins_home"
    container_image     = var.image
    region              = var.deployment_region
    account_id          = var.account
    log_group           = data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state_ecs.outputs.logs_name
    memory              = var.jenkins_memory
    cpu                 = var.jenkins_cpu
  }
}


resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" jenkins_controller {
  family = var.appName
  task_role_arn            = data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state_iam.outputs.master_task_arn
  execution_role_arn       = data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state_iam.outputs.jenkins_execution_arn
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = var.jenkins_cpu
  memory                   = var.jenkins_memory
  container_definitions    = data.template_file.jenkins_container_def.rendered

  volume {
    name = "${var.appName}-efs"

    efs_volume_configuration {
      file_system_id     = data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state_efs.outputs.efs_fs_id
      transit_encryption = "ENABLED"

      authorization_config {
        access_point_id = flatten(data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state_efs.outputs.efs_access_point_id)[0]
        iam             = "ENABLED"
      }
    }
  }

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" jenkins_controller {
  name = "${var.prefix}-${var.appName}-controller-service"

  task_definition  = aws_ecs_task_definition.jenkins_controller.arn
  cluster          = data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state_ecs.outputs.ecs_cluster_id
  desired_count    = 1
  launch_type      = "FARGATE"
  platform_version = "1.4.0"

  // Assuming we cannot have more than one instance at a time. Ever.
  deployment_maximum_percent         = 100
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 0


  service_registries {
    registry_arn = aws_service_discovery_service.controller.arn
   }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state_alb.outputs.tg_arn
    container_name   = "${var.prefix}-${var.appName}"
    container_port   = 8080
  }

  network_configuration {
    subnets          = flatten([module.vpc_presets.subnet_ids])

    security_groups  = data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state_sg.outputs.ecs_sg
    assign_public_ip = false
  }
  tags           = var.tags
}
```

Comment: You think that this can be IAM issue, but you are not showing any of your iam policies and roles used in your setup.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

It was an IAM policy issue. issues got fixed after changing the policy.

Comment: could you please elaborate on how you resolved this by changing the IAM policy? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @RanganaSampath what issue you are facing?

Comment: Same thing you mentioned in the question  "ResourceInitializationError: failed to invoke EFS utils commands to set up EFS volumes: stderr: b'mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting 127.0.0.1:/' : unsuccessful EFS utils command execution; code: 32"

Comment: please elaborate on how you resolved this

Answer (score 1):

I had a related problem because the directory has not yet been created, there is a property in root_directory that allows creating the directory with proper permissions.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/efs_access_point#creation_info

In the example I use root, but you can set another gid.

```terraform
resource "aws_efs_access_point" this  {
  file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.efs.id
  root_directory {
    path = "/desired-directory"
    creation_info {
      owner_gid = 0
      owner_uid = 0
      permissions = "755"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this WORKED for me!

1. delete and recreate EFS via AWS CLI as below.
2. create 2 mount points inside EFS
3. add security group flag to compose (--security-groups sg-0x1578xxxxdbc94x4)

*Delete old and re-Create file system programatically*

```
export AWS_EFS_FILESYSTEM_ID=$( \
  aws efs create-file-system \
    --creation-token hello-world-efs \
    --no-encrypt \
    --throughput-mode bursting \
    --performance-mode generalPurpose \
    --region us-west-2 \
    | jq --raw-output ".FileSystemId"
)
```

*Create mount targets*

```
aws efs create-mount-target \
  --file-system-id ${AWS_EFS_FILESYSTEM_ID} \
  --security-groups ${AWS_EC2_SECURITY_GROUP} \
  --subnet-id ${AWS_SUBNET_ID_1}

aws efs create-mount-target \
  --file-system-id ${AWS_EFS_FILESYSTEM_ID} \
  --security-groups ${AWS_EC2_SECURITY_GROUP} \
  --subnet-id ${AWS_SUBNET_ID_2}
```

This solution is from: https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli/issues/1083

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using AWS Copilot. The problem was that the security group that Copilot created for the EFS volume wasn't automatically linked to the Copilot job that needed it. Make sure that the security group which grants access to EFS is also attached to the ECS instance.

There are at least two ways to solve the Copilot problem, one is to manually grab the security group ID from AWS and plug it in, like below:

```
network:
  vpc:
    security_groups:
      # Attaches the security group to grant permissions for this task
      - "sg-0123456..."
```

Another way is to make it more automated, which helps a lot when you have multiple environments and don't want to manually set it for each one. First update the `environments/overrides/cfn.patches.yaml` to have the following:

```
- op: add
  path: /Outputs/ManagedFileSystemSecurityGroup
  value:
    Condition: CreateEFS
    Value: !Ref EFSSecurityGroup
    Description: The ID of the Copilot-managed EFS security group.
    Export:
        Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-FilesystemSecurityGroup
```

Then update the `[service name]/overrides/cfn.patches.yaml` to include that in the security groups. The indices might need to change a bit if you're already including other security groups or not.

```
- op: add
  path: /Resources/StateMachine/Properties/DefinitionSubstitutions/SecurityGroups/Fn::Join/1/-
  value: 
    Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${AppName}-${EnvName}-FilesystemSecurityGroup'
```